# How to check if string begins with a square bracked in bash

Tags: bash

I need to go through my ini file and check if the line begins with a bracket, to figure out that the new config has started. Is there a way of checking this in bash? I tried

```
line="[test]"

if [[ "$line" =~ [.* ]]; then
    echo "Got it!"
else
    echo "Nothing found"
fi
```

but it doesn't work for me. I presume that the bracket needs to be somehow escaped, but I can't find any info as to how. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a regex for this, a simple glob pattern will suffice: `if [[ $line == \[* ]]; ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you should backslash the special character `[`, so :

```
line='[test]'

if [[ $line =~ ^\[ ]]; then
    echo "Got it!"
else
    echo "Nothing found"
fi
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- `[` is the starting character to opening a [REGEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) class, like `[0-9]`
- quotes are needed everywhere but not inside `bash` `[[ ]]` tests

Comment: As question was **string begins with a square bracked**, there miss à `^` sign!

Answer (score 0):

It's terrible to use a regexp for that! please use a `bash` glob instead:

```
if [[ $line = [* ]]; then
    echo 'Got it!'
else
    echo "Nothing found"
fi
```

Hope this helps use `bash` more efficiently.